# Move from local linux folder to a windows share mounted with cifs

Tags: python, linux, windows, file-io, share

I need to move files in a script from a local folder on an ext4 hdd to a folder which is a windows share mounted like: `mount -t cifs -o username=username,password=password,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 //192.168.1.120/storage /mnt/storage`

I tried to use `os.rename(src,dst)`, `shutil.move(src,dst)` and even `subprocess.call(['mv', src,dst], Shell=True)` or `subprocess.call(['mv', src,dst])`

Get errors for every file and from what I can tell its because of the linux file ownership/permissions..

e.g. when `mv /mnt/networkshare/file1.txt /tmp/file1.txt` is fine, but

```
mv /tmp/file1.txt /mnt/networkshare/file1.txt
```

results in

```
"mv: preserving times for /mnt/networkshare/file1.txt: Operation not permitted"
"mv preserving permissions for /mnt/networkshare/file1.txt: Operation not permitted"
```

I assume that the same problem occurs with `os.rename(src,dst)` and `shutil.move(src,dst)`, yet they are not that talkative.

`shutil.move(src,dst)` tells me: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/mnt/networkshare/file1.txt'

and `os.rename(src,dst)` says: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link

edit: pcmanfm is able to cut and paste from local to remote just fine.

plus.. what baffles me is that some files are moved..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`os.rename` can't move files across filesystems, because the underlying [`rename` syscall](http://linux.die.net/man/2/rename) won't allow it:

> rename() does not work across different mount points, even if the same
>   filesystem is mounted on both.

As to why `shutil.move` fails, the answer, too, lies in [its documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.move):

> If the destination is on the current filesystem, then simply use
>   rename. Otherwise, copy src (with copy2()) to the dst and then remove
>   src.

Let's [check `copy2`](https://docs.python.org/2.6/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2) then!

> Similar to copy(), but metadata is copied as well – in fact, this is
>   just copy() followed by copystat()

So, it's that `copystat` that is failing - because it can't set the file metadata on such a mount.

Since `shutil` doesn't seem to have a method to rename without copying metadata, we'll have to do it ourselves. Let's take a look at its source code:

```
In [3]: print inspect.getsource(shutil.move)
def move(src, dst):
    """Recursively move a file or directory to another location. This is
    similar to the Unix "mv" command.

    If the destination is a directory or a symlink to a directory, the source
    is moved inside the directory. The destination path must not already
    exist.

    If the destination already exists but is not a directory, it may be
    overwritten depending on os.rename() semantics.

    If the destination is on our current filesystem, then rename() is used.
    Otherwise, src is copied to the destination and then removed.
    A lot more could be done here...  A look at a mv.c shows a lot of
    the issues this implementation glosses over.

    """
    real_dst = dst
    if os.path.isdir(dst):
        if _samefile(src, dst):
            # We might be on a case insensitive filesystem,
            # perform the rename anyway.
            os.rename(src, dst)
            return

        real_dst = os.path.join(dst, _basename(src))
        if os.path.exists(real_dst):
            raise Error, "Destination path '%s' already exists" % real_dst
    try:
        os.rename(src, real_dst)
    except OSError:
        if os.path.isdir(src):
            if _destinsrc(src, dst):
                raise Error, "Cannot move a directory '%s' into itself '%s'." % (src, dst)
            copytree(src, real_dst, symlinks=True)
            rmtree(src)
        else:
            copy2(src, real_dst)
            os.unlink(src)
```

It seems that, as predicted, all we need to do is replace `copy2` by `copy`. We can do that by either copying over the source code and renaming the function or simply by

```
def move_without_copying_stat(src,dst):
    old= shutil.copy2
    shutil.copy2= shutil.copy
    shutil.move(src,dst)
    shutil.copy2= old
```

if you're feeling lucky today. Understanding [the consequences of such](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch#Pitfalls) is left as an exercise to the reader

Answer (score 1):

Since python version 3.5, you can call:

```py
shutil.move(src, dst, copy_function=shutil.copyfile)
```

`shutil.copyfile` only copies file content, it doesn't preserve permissions and metadata